# How to force all external links to open in iframe

Tags: php

need to force all external links in my website to open in iframe link will be like this 
ex : `http://google.com/iframe=http://externallink.com/dgfg` title "from external link "
is it passable to do it with sample code in footer ?>

Comment: Where is the code you have tried? Where exactly did you need help?

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){
   $('a').attr('target', 'iframeNameHere');
});

i need help in all pages in my website , any external link will be open in iframe